# Does sudo snap purge remove all of my snap folders

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, snap

Snaps daemon failed to start on my desktop so I want to reinstall snap without deleting any of my downloaded snap files firefox web browser was downloaded through snap and I don’t want it to be deleted, will using the command `sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd` only remove snap or will it also delete my snap firefox fire?

The output of `ps -ef | grep snap is`

```
Myusername 4611 1634 0 20:27 pts/1 00:00:00 Grep ——color=auto snap
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) And provide us more detail.

Comment: What is the output of `ps -ef | grep snap` and add to your [question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1489931/edit)

Comment: It’s been added stumblebee